Non-ideal active low pass filter for LV25P output
Hello everyone I need some help understanding the active low-pass filter below.
I was told to use this circuit to filter the measurements of the output voltage of an inverter, but there is no documentation for the circuit.
I have done an analysis using ideal components and I understand that C1 is a decoupling capacitor and reduces the noise from the input source, and that R1 and C2 make a simple low-pass filter with a pole at approx 145 kHz = -1/(R1*C2).
However when I perform an AC analysis on the circuit below I get a cutoff frequency closer to 1 kHz, so the transfer function clearly has an earlier pole, but I am not sure how to derive this from the diagram.
I am specifically confused about the purpose of R2 at the + terminal of op amp and the C3 connecting the filter input to the output.
The op amp used for the physical implementation is:TL081CP
The current source is generated by: LV25P

Thank you very much for your time!
Note: In my initial post I had replaced the current source and R3 with a voltage source, which significantly changed the behavior of the circuit. Thanks to Andy aka, periblepsis, and Spehro Pefhany for pointing this out.

The circuit is almost certainly incorrect. You need to replicate what was asked of you or, if indeed the circuit above came from the person recommending it, choose a different/better person to help you.

@Andyaka, thank you for the pointing this out. I have mad the requested changes to the diagram.

The circuit still makes no sense. It is likely  a mistake in what the original person told you or, a mistake in what you thought he told you. I didn't request changes BTW.

@Larcron What kind of damping/Q and gain (if any) do you want in a 2nd order filter here? And by the way, what roll-off do you imagine getting with 100 Ohms and 1.9 uF? Looks like about 840 Hz to me. Yeah, that has an earlier pole. This really looks like a senseless circuit with hunt-and-peck (random) poking of values. Finally, the AC part is usually used with "1". Why did you use "25m" there?

@periblepsis Yes, I am starting to suspect that this circuit is a botched attempt at a Sallen-Key filter like Spehro Pefhany suggested. If I move C2 to the + terminal  of the op amp and connect C3 between R1 and R2 (making a Sallen-Key filter), my spice simulations suggests it becomes an objectively better filter with a faster roll off starting at about 5 kHz.
I will ask my colleague tomorrow, and if this is the case I will post an update here.

@periblepsis For the AC part, the max current we are expecting is 25mA, so I set the AC amplitude to that. I am getting the gain between input current and output voltage, so I have not been paying too much attention to the dB values. But yes, I realize that could be a bit misleading
In terms of voltage, I want unity gain within the pass-band (which I am getting).
Regarding frequency ,we are measuring the outputs of a grid tied inverter, so we are interested in frequencies around 50 or 60 Hz. The inverter switching frequency is around 20 kHz, so we want that well within the stop band.

@Larcron If you set the LP corner at, say, 100 Hz, then a 2nd order should be down by over 90 dB by 20 kHz. I suspect that should be fine for you. But I worry about 1/f noise since your frequency of interest suggests a need for some concern here. So check your amplifier's noise curve, consider a band-pass, and also consider choppers, as they may be able to help some (see here for some discussion.)

R2 acts as another (poorly defined) low pass filter with the input and stray capacitance of a few pF, so cutoff frequency of a few hundred kHz.
I'm going to assume below that C1, C3 and R1 are supposed to be connected together, however they are not connected in your simulation (there is no square dot indicating a connection).
In the simulation, C1 will do nothing unless you add some source resistance to the Measurement source.
The same goes for C3 except it will negatively affect the stability of the op-amp a bit. As the value is acceptably low and this is a LPF probably you won't see much effect with or without it.
This appears to be an attempt at a Sallen-Key filter, which is sensitive to source impedance at the best of times. This is not the best of times, since all of Z1 is hidden in the source. Also there's C1..
Anyway, the response will be highly dependent on the source resistance. If it is controlled (maybe you have a current transformer with a known burden resistor, for example) you should model that resistance or you'll get results that may be far from reality.

It's not clear to me that this was a carefully designed circuit, or maybe it has lost something in the translation.

Thanks for the response!
The filter was originally connected to a LV25P voltage transducer with a measurement resistor with approximately 100 ohm , but I am considering adding a voltage buffer to avoid interfering with the voltage across the measurement resistor.
If my understanding is correct, using this buffer will render C1 and C3 useless?
Also thanks for pointing out the error in the simulation. I will make sure to correct that in my original post.

@Larcron If you haven't already done so, you should include this 100 Ohm resistor for the LV25P output. It's effectively the source impedance as the LV25P should have an output impedance itself that is very very high. So the 100 Ohms will dominate if I'm getting that part right. Since a current source and 100 Ohms is equivalent to an ideal Thevenin source with an output impedance of 100 Ohms, you can just point that out as part of the design. Also note it's dynamic range, too, and any power supply limitations you have to consider.

Okay. I think you've finally written down enough information to get a start on the filter.

\$100\:\Omega\$ source impedance
interested in \$50\:\text{Hz} \le f \le 60\:\text{Hz}\$
remove inverter switching frequency near \$20\:\text{kHz}\$
interested in \$A_v=1\$
considering active low-pass filter

I'll mention just two opamps that specify about the same voltage noise and are both rail to rail input and output. I'm not recommending either. But just offering them as decent and worth actually building up into two different prototypes that you can use to check out the difference for your application between a chopper amplifier and a more typical opamp without chopping. These two are the LT1800 (non-chopper) and the OPA388 (chopper.)
I started out thinking about 2nd order active filter but then decided (given everything else) that it may be nicer to recommend something that involves more opamps but is also simple and will let you make modifications to it that affect one kind of parameter without impacting others, if you want. And I definitely wanted to avoid discussing state-variable.
I'm going to select \$\approx 100\:\text{Hz}\$ as the corner frequency and since I don't think you care about high-Q and I'd like to avoid highly-damped as well, I'd like to design this around critical-damping, which is similar to RC filter rolloff behavior.
Just keeping this as simple as possible and the most likely to succeed, while allowing adjustment options later on if you need to try something.
So I have picked the following topology:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Keep \$R_3=R_4\$, \$R_5=R_6\$, and \$C_1=C_2\$. This let's you control the gain with \$R_1\$ (when the sum of your source/burden resistor plus \$R_1\$ is the same as \$R_3\$ then the gain is just 1.) Reducing \$R_1\$ will increase the gain and increasing \$R_1\$ will reduce the gain. Also, this means that \$R_2\$ can be independently modified to change the damping factor (or Q) without altering the rolloff frequency.
If you want the details, \$A_v=\frac{R_3}{R_1}\frac{R_5}{R_6}\$, \$\zeta=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{C_2}{C_1}}\sqrt{\frac{R_5}{R_6}}\frac{\sqrt{R_3 R_4}}{R_2}\$, and \$\omega_0=\frac1{\sqrt{C_1 C_2 R_3 R_4 \frac{R_5}{R_6}}}\$.
You will need bipolar power supplies, I think. Your sensor requires them and so does the above circuit. If you need the output adjusted (moved so that it is always positive), then there are more than a few ways to get that done. But the above is a start, at least. And it should behave itself reasonably well.

Circuit analysis on a topological basis and application of the node voltages method.

